# Extracting cities in Belgium using overpass API?

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I would like to extract all the cities in Belgium using the overpass API.I used the following query:

```
area[name="België - Belgique - Belgien"]->.boundaryarea;
(
  node(area.boundaryarea)[place="city"];
);

out;
```

But got no result. Am I doing something wrong?

---

This appears to work but I have no idea why

```
{{geocodeArea:Netherlands}}->.searchArea;
(
nwr["place"="city"](area.searchArea);
);
out body;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/52411 you need to use `area[name="België / Belgique / Belgien"]`, and not as you stated `area[name="België - Belgique - Belgien"]` (note the typo, the `name` tag has to match *exactly*!).

In case case, I would highly recommend to use some more stable identifier instead, e.g. `area["ISO3166-1"="BE"][boundary=administrative]`.

Full query:

```
area["ISO3166-1"="BE"][boundary=administrative];
node(area)[place="city"];
out body;
```